# Profile Picture disappears when error

Tags: bug, profile-picture, profile-page

I was trying to change my Display name to some thing new. And I changed twice today but when I try to change the name again the error Message apperas:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile: Display name may only
>   be changed once every 30 days; you may change again on Aug 30 at 18:35

But at the same time my profile picture is not showing it disappears?

Check the Image Below:

[image]

Comment: I was able to replicate this behavior. However, it didn't save the broken image in my case (I had messed up my email address to replicate)

Comment: In my case too it is not removed completely but don't show when error appears.!!

Comment: The profile picture is not disappearing, it's defaulting to Gravatar. If you'll add Gravatar picture as well you'll see it appearing. (without picture it's showing identicon based on your email)

Comment: I mentioned that My Profile picture is disappearing! I made uploaded image as profile picture.. so if any images other than the one i uploaded comes means it means my profile picture disappears :)

Comment: Not only does *this* happen, it also shows the name updated